# .net how to convert python repr() string to byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, string

is there any simple way to get a byte array of escaped string (Python repr() style) provided as TextBox input?

Example:

I want to convert string like this:

```
"ab\\x01c"
```

to array like this:

```
array[0] = 0x61;  
array[1] = 0x62;  
array[2] = 0x01;  
array[3] = 0x63;
```

Comment: you won't get that array, unless you want the characters to be uppercased before conversion to bytes.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: I don't get your comment. 0x61 is 'a' so what is the problem?

Comment: ha! sorry, I miss read them as decimal, not hexadecimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
private string HexToStringMatchEvaluator(Match match)
{
    int intValue = int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    return Convert.ToChar(intValue).ToString();
}
...
string source = "ab\\x01c";
source = Regex.Replace(source, @"\\x(\d\d)", HexToStringMatchEvaluator);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(source);
```

A brief explanation:

Regex.Replace looks for occurences of `\x` followed by two digits and passes each `Match` to our custom MatchEvaluator. The evaluator converts the specified value from hex to decimal and then to its equivalent Unicode character. The rest is obvious, I hope.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you got an extra \ before the x (you're using @")

Comment: @Aviad P., no, there _must_ be 2 slashes in the regex: remember, we need to find a slash, followed by character 'x', followed by 2 digits. But in order to find a slash we must prefix literal '\' with another one, since the slash itself is an escape character in regexes. Without @ regex string would look like `"\\\\x(\\d\\d)"`.